# How to apart Exponential function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to apart Exponential function in python.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import t
from sympy import exp

u = (3*(exp(4*t) - 1)*exp(-4*t))/4
apart = sym.apart(u, t)
print(apart)
```

But i get the error:

> exp(4*t) contains an element of the set of generators

Answer (score 1):

it looks like exp() is confusing it. For a workaround

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import t,z
from sympy import exp

u = (3*(exp(4*t) - 1)*exp(-4*t))/4
expr = sym.apart(u.subs(exp(t),z), z)
expr = expr.subs(z,exp(t))
```

Which gives

```
Out[3]: 3/4 - 3*exp(-4*t)/4
```

Using 3.7 on conda

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is a univariate, rational function in terms of exp(t):

```
>>> u.subs(exp(t),y)
3*(y**4 - 1)/(4*y**4)
>>> apart(_)
3/4 - 3/(4*y**4)
>>> _.subs(y, exp(t))
3/4 - 3*exp(-4*t)/4
```

But SymPy can handle such non-symbol generators so for such an expression `sym.apart(u)` would have given the same result as shown above. When you said the generator was `t` it detected the `exp(t)` and raised the error since an expression like `t + exp(t)` has two generators that depend on `t`.